# how to establish connection through irDA sockets?

Tags: c++, network-programming, infrared

in our study of network programming we began with irDA programming so I have two irDA adapters "Kingsun KS-959 USB Infrared Adapter" and two old computers running windows xp sp2.

I installed correctly the adapters on both machines.

I wanted to create Server/Client in irDA. here is a sample of irServer irClient:

```
// irServer:

#define BACKLOG 2
WORD    wVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
WSADATA wSaData;

if(WSAStartup(wVersion, &wSaData))
    return -1;

int irSockServ = socket(AF_IRDA, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(SOCKET_ERROR == irSockServ)
    DieWithError(WSAGetLastError());

SOCKADDR_IRDA sa_irda_serv = {AF_IRDA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                            "irDA:irCOMM"};
if(SOCKET_ERROR == bind(irSockServ, (SOCKADDR*)&sa_irda_serv, sizeof(sa_irda_serv)))
    DieWithError(WSAGetLastError());
if(SOCKET_ERROR == listen(irSockServ, BACKLOG))
    DieWithError(WSAGetLastError());

SOCKADDR_IRDA sa_irda_clnt;
int sa_irda_clnt_len = sizeof(sa_irda_clnt);
int irSockClnt = accept(irSockServ, (SOCKADDR*)&sa_irda_clnt, &sa_irda_clnt_len);

if(SOCKET_ERROR == irSockClnt)
    DieWithError(WSAGetLastError());
else
    cout << "Client! Connected" << std::endl;
```

and here is a sample of irClient:

```
WORD    wVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
WSADATA wSaData;

if(WSAStartup(wVersion, &wSaData))
    return -1;

int irSockClnt = socket(AF_IRDA, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(SOCKET_ERROR == irSockClnt)
    DieWithError(WSAGetLastError());

DEVICELIST DevLst;
int DevLstLen = sizeof(DEVICELIST);

while(1)
{
    Sleep(1000);
    DevLst.numDevice = 0;

    // enumerating in range irDA devices
    if(SOCKET_ERROR == getsockopt(irSockClnt, SOL_IRLMP, 
        IRLMP_ENUMDEVICES, (char*)&DevLst, &DevLstLen))
        DieWithError(WSAGetLastError());
    if(DevLst.numDevice)
    {
        cout << "Device Name: " << DevLst.Device[0].irdaDeviceName << endl;

        SOCKADDR_IRDA sa_irda_serv;
        sa_irda_serv.irdaAddressFamily = AF_IRDA;
        strcpy(sa_irda_serv.irdaServiceName, "irDA:irCOMM");
        memcpy(&sa_irda_serv.irdaDeviceID[0], &DevLst.Device[0].irdaDeviceID[0], 4);

        // the problem is here it still stuck and won't connect!??
        if(SOCKET_ERROR == connect(irSockClnt, (SOCKADDR*)&sa_irda_serv, sizeof(sa_irda_serv)))
            DieWithError(WSAGetLastError());
    }
}
```

I get everything working until issuing a connection so `connect` still stuck and therefore no connection is established.

I appreciate any king of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server implementation, place`accept()` in a `while(1)` loop.

You don't need to wait in the `while(1)` loop for the `connect()` in the **client** implementation.

**Server**

```
while(1) {
...
 accept(...);
 Sleep(Number_of_miliseconds);//You are using win32 imp, for POSIX sleep() this will be in seconds
...
}
```

Comment: but accept is a blocking API. and even doing so the problem is the same. anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: is there another suggestion?

Comment: Can you test Infra Red connections are working through OS? Once two systems are connected, can you also test if you can transfer files through the IR connection?

Comment: no! I can send to phone via infrared but from pc to pc no??!! I don't know why???!!! please help out it's so important and stuck

Comment: Have you tried this link, https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/irda_ras_make_connect.mspx?mfr=true ?

Comment: I followed everything on the link but I cant transfer data from pc to the other?!

Comment: Driver settings may be the answer. If you can access the driver settings, it should provide the windows registry specific information. Device registry settings may enable you to connect two machines.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: using an irDA usb does it matter?? the old version used usb to srial

Comment: You can access Windows Registry. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/wdf/introduction-to-registry-keys-for-drivers. Also, from device manager, you should see your devices and which registry keys it is mapped to. By default, a PC driver profile may only enabled to work on Server node. In linux, this page contains the attribute tree for this device driver. https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-720083-view-next.html?sid=44cf2b3c7e3bfedcd10c808268c1230a . bmAttributes{Transfer Type, Synch Type,  Usage Type} might be present in Windows also. Can you connect to a phoneIRDA?

Comment: in fact I can send from mobile "T610" to computer via irDA and the contrary. but from computer to computer no!! each computer detects the other for example I get the message while hovering mouse on irDA icon "user is in range" but if I send to it something I can't; it blocks. nor I can connect using socket in c++. if you advise me how to do that on fedora. it will be a good idea. I'll give up it on windows

Comment: Can you server socket read establish a connection with phone?

Comment: normally yes. but I wonder I don't know the `service name ` on phone and even though I can connect to phone from my socket client!!

Comment: Cahit Gungor: I read all the pages you sent to me. but nothing helped me out. does the problem belongs to this type of adapters?

Comment: What about the windows registry settings for your device? Are you able to locate them?

Comment: yes I locate them but don't know what to do with them?

Comment: Are there any entries in the Windows Registry naming similar to below? I try to change them first. (If driver contains a documentation, please follow that first.) bmAttributes            3 
          Transfer Type            Interrupt 
          Synch Type               None 
          Usage Type               Data

Comment: @CahitGungor: this is my account because the one above I forgot its credentials. I can't find any drivers you are talking about please help I am still stuck.

Comment: The irDA adaptor might have a driver that should be available on Internet. The specific Brand and Model Number should lead you to the driver on the Internet, most probably manufacturer site.